# How to make python interpreter ask for input and write to file

Tags: python-3.x

How to make my code execute the input and write function infinitely without copy pasting it a lot?

```
import time
now = time.strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y:")

text = str(input("Nodus: "))

Nodus = open("Diário.txt","a") 
Nodus.write(time.strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y:"))
Nodus.write(' "%s"' % text)
Nodus.write("\n")
Nodus.close()


tet = open("Diário.txt","r")
tet2 = tet.read()
print (tet2)

time.sleep(5)
text = str(input("Nodus: "))
time.sleep(5)
text = str(input("Nodus: "))
time.sleep(5)
text = str(input("Nodus: "))
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Have you heard of loops? You may want to read the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: It's that I can't think of a way to do that, like in "text = str(input("Nodus: "))", what I use?, "for" or "while"?

Answer (score 0):

So, you should have a while loop, and you should keep the write part in a function.

```
def write(input_):
    Nodus = open("Diário.txt","a") 
    Nodus.write(time.strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y:"))
    Nodus.write(' "%s"' % input_)
    Nodus.write("\n")
    Nodus.close()

running = True

while running:
    text = str(input("Nodus: "))
    try:
        write(text)
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        print('Error in command.')
```

So this should be the finished code:

```
import time
now = time.strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y:")

def write(input_):
    Nodus = open("Diário.txt","a") 
    Nodus.write(time.strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y:"))
    Nodus.write(' "%s"' % input_)
    Nodus.write("\n")
    Nodus.close()

running = True

while running:
    text = str(input("Nodus: "))
    try:
        write(text)
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        print('Error in command.')

tet = open("Diário.txt","r")
tet2 = tet.read()
print (tet2)
```

Comment: It gets and error of no types selected on the exception, also the input ask appears in the console and I write something, but it doesn't write in the .txt file, see my code here  [link] (https://repl.it/repls/Python-Testing-File)

Comment: Oh. I am sorry I did not understand the question. Let me fix the answer

Comment: Oh, thanks for the help, I also added a exit command, if the user type "/sair" the script cancels the text input, I would like to make a command to run another script, the "nodus" one i use to write as nodus, so I would like to type "/izaque" and run the izaque.py script.

Comment: I also made some changes to the code, I made a "command" thing, to select to write tags, write as izaque and write as nodus, here:

Comment: Sorry for posting too much, but I need help, check the repl it, when it run and i type "/nodus" it goes into nodus mode, but when I'm in nodus mode and type "/izaque" the script stops, when I'm in izaque mode and type "/nodus" it changes to nodus normally.